# How to pass a param to an AngularJS $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources

Most tutorials show you how to list a resource (say entries), and then they show how to link to an individual entry from the list view (`/entries`). This is great as individual entries are available to the controller scope, so you can wire up a resource like this:

```
app.factory('Entry', [ '$resource', function ($resource) {
  $resource('/entries/:id', { id: '@id' });
]});

app.controller('EntryController', [ '$scope', 'Entry', function ($scope, Entry) {
  $scope.entries = Entry.query();
}]);
```

But I have not seen any examples that show you how to pass the resource id if you are starting out on `/entries/1`. How do you pass entry id, `1`, from the view without having access to the array of `entries`?

I'm working on a single page that allows a user to interact with a single `entry` object. There is not `entries` view, so I'm not sure how to get Angular to load an individual entry.

I'm using Rails.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample above, try this:

```
var sampleID = $resource('/entries/:id', { id: '@id' });
sampleID.get({id:123}).$promise.then(function(data) {
  //Do something with data
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my issue is where to get the '123'. More precisely, how to pass it from the template the JS file. so `...get({id: some_variable_that_has_id })`